# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'keyof IMyObj' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to avoid any type in typescript and trying to set a value by accessing its key but facing the below typescript error. I had seen many stackoverflow post but couldnt figure out to fix this.

I have issue with my code similar and tried to replicate with sample one.

```
type IMyObj = {
          title: string
          content: string
        }
        type IMyObj1 = {
          titles: string
          content1: string
        }
        const myObj: IMyObj = {
          title: 'Hi',
          content: 'Hope all is well',
        }
          const myObj: IMyObj1 = {
          titles: 'Hi',
          content1: 'Hope all is well',
        }



        const myKey: string = 'content'

        myObj[myKey as keyof IMyObj] = 'All is great now!'  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'keyof IMyObj' can't be used to index type 'IMyObj | IMyObj1'.
```

Property 'title' does not exist on type 'IMyObj | IMyObj1'.ts(7053)
No quick fixes available

**My actual code is the below**

I have to give a type to currentValue which is passed to the method in this case, so I cannot omit the the type here.

```
const formatData = (
    faData: FinancialSection[],
    faSection: keyof FinancialSection
  ) => ({
    ..._.sortBy(
      faData,
      (item: FinancialSection) => item.period.year
    ).reduce((actualValue: any, currentValue: FinancialSection) => {
      Object.keys(ProfitAndLossKeys).forEach((key: string) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        if (!actualValue[key]) actualValue[key] = { values: [] }
        actualValue[key].values.push(
          currentValue[faSection] && currentValue[faSection][key] !== null
            ? currentValue[faSection][key]    //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ProfitLossData | KeyFiguresData | BalanceSheetData | CashFlowData | Period'.
```

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ProfitLossData | KeyFiguresData | BalanceSheetData | CashFlowData | Period'.ts(7053)
: null
)
})
return actualValue
}, {})
})

Answer (score 0):

Your typing of the object is wrong.

```
const myObj: IMyObj | IMyObj1 =
```

means that you're telling TypeScript that it's *either* a `IMyObj`, *or* a `IMyObj1`. But the object contains all properties of both, so you should use `&`, not `|`.

```
const myObj: IMyObj & IMyObj1 = {
```

That'll fix your error - but it'd be even easier to omit the types entirely and let TS infer it (which it'll do properly).

```
const myObj = {
    title: 'Hi',
    content: 'Hope all is well',
    titles: 'Hi',
    content1: 'Hope all is well'
}
const myKey = 'content'

myObj[myKey] = 'All is great now!'
```

Comment: I have updated my actual code, I cannot omit my type here. currentValue[faSection][key]  the key is causing the issue here.

Comment: I have updated the sample when Iterating the objects, object will be different with different properties

Comment: Please make sure the code in your question represents what you actually have when you first post it. There are lots of undeclared types in your code at the moment, could you edit it so that everything is declared and it doesn't have type errors (except for the one you're asking about, of course)? That way, with nearly working representative code, it can be debugged

Comment: code is running properly when I try to change the any type and giving a proper type facing the issue.  reduce((actualValue: any, currentValue: FinancialSection)  when I change from FinancialSection to any it is working properly.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't address what I was asking, nor does using `any` make sense in TypeScript - it defeats the whole point of the type system